# How to create an array of records in BizTalk

Tags: xsd, biztalk

I have an xsd type which consists of some elements. One of the elements is defined like
`<xs:element name="Parameters" type="ParametersType" />` where `ParametersType` is

```
<xs:complexType name="ParametersType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Parameter"
                    type="ParameterType"
                    minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element name="UserDefinedParameter"
                    type="xs:base64Binary"
                    minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1">
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

That is, I have an array of `Parameter` type records. So I have 2 questions so far:

1. Ноw to initialize such array and how to work with it in Expression block;
2. How to tune mapping from incoming message of the same type to my message?

Answer (score 3):

When we talk about arrays here we are really talking about nested, repeatable nodes within your message.

One solution is to decompose your array inside a loop in your orchestration.

This is not simple, but here is an example:

[image: Deconstructing nested repeatable message section inside biztalk orch]

The code inside the various expression shapes:

Inside "Count array items"

```
intCountArrayItems = xpath(MyMessage, "count(XpathToParameterNodeInYourMessage)");
```

Inside "foreach array item"

```
intLoopIndex < intCountArrayItems
```

Inside "Use array item"

```
strXPathToArrayItem = System.String.Format("XpathToParameterNodeInYourMessage[{0}]", intLoopIndex + 1);
MyXmlDocument = xpath(MyMessage, strXPathToArrayItem);
// Now you can do what you want with the xml document.
```

Inside "Increment loop index"

```
intLoopIndex = intLoopIndex + 1;
```

The above gives you a way to decompose an array inside your orchestration and access each of  your "Paramter" types as an xml document (which you can then do stuff with).

Hope this helps.

Comment: And how to create a new array of parameters? For instance, I have 2 parameters - user login and domain name - and I want to fill a Parameters array with 2 records.

Comment: @javros can you explain in more detail. I don't know what "I want to fill a Parameters array with 2 records" means

Comment: OK. I have a `ProviderRequest` element, inside it I have `Parameters` element which consists of a sequence of elements of type `Parameter`. The latter consists of `Name` and `Value` elements (string). It looks like <ProviderRequest><Parameters><Parameter><Name>Issuer</Name><Value>John</Value></Parameter><Parameter><Name>Date</Name><Value>2011-09-13T10:43:00</Value></Parameter></Parameters></ProviderRequest>. How would I fill <Parameters> element in BizTalk?